# Update Google Forms field based on dynamic data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

In a *Google Form* we have a pull down selection list.

The list of items may change from minute to minute. The master copy of the data is in a column in a google docs spreadsheet.

When a user accesses the form, we want them to see the latest copy of the pull down list as is current in the spreadsheet.

I don't see an obvious way to do this with triggers. onOpen, for example, only triggers for administrators of the form, not users. Is there a way I can keep this form up-to-date automatically?

This is my first time in google docs, but I'm very experienced in excel scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work flow needs to be a bit different than what you've described. Since there is no ability for Google Apps Script to interact with an end user accessing a Form, there's no way to react to that. However, you *can* react to changes in the spreadsheet, and update the form options in preparation for the next end user.

- Depending on how the options get updated in the spreadsheet, you can use an installable trigger there, to react to an edit or a change.
- If the form is associated with the spreadsheet containing the choices, you can get a handle on the form using [`Spreadsheet.getFormUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getFormUrl()), then pass the URL to [`FormApp.openByUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openByUrl(String)). Otherwise you will need to provide the ID or URL explicitly to [`FormApp.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openById(String)) or `.openByUrl()`, respectively.
- That spreadsheet trigger function can modify the available selections for the relevant question by using [`ListItem.setChoices()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#setChoices(Choice)) or [`ListItem.setChoiceValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#setChoiceValues(String)).