# Pull-down list by another answer in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to make a booking form using **Google Form** and **Google Apps Script**.

A user visits this form, and then

1. The user selects the date he/she wants to book in the first
   section.

This booking system

2. Access the calendar to get the schedule of the day.
3. Make a pull-down time list he/she can book in.
4. Display a question with the pull-down list in the second section.

Can I make such a form with Google Form? And if I can, tell me how to make this form?

Comment: Some workarounds are possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894664/update-google-forms-field-based-on-dynamic-data-from-a-google-sheets-spreadsheet?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489864/dynamic-selection-options-in-google-apps-script-for-forms?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic selection options in Google Apps Script for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489864/dynamic-selection-options-in-google-apps-script-for-forms)